# A simple If...else block. Why is it doing nothing?

Tags: javascript

```
 <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
     <script type = "text/javascript">
      var x = 5;
      var y = 8;
      if (x < 6)
      {
       document.write("They are equal");
      }
      else
      {
       document.write{"They are NOT equal");
      }
     </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A proper editor or JS debugger in the browser would show the syntax error. Maybe you want to have a look at Komodo Edit http://www.activestate.com/komodo_edit/ and Firebug for Firefox http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Also turning on script debugging.

Comment: Try JSLint or JavascriptLint, they will save you tons of time with these types of problems

Comment: We've ALL been here!  :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you have a syntax error:

```
document.write{"They are NOT equal");
```

Should be

```
document.write("They are NOT equal");
```

Comment: damn it. I can't believe I didnt see this after 15 minutes :( Thanks ChaosPandion!

Comment: you should see if it's possible to code in a font that will reduce this problem.